# При добавлении в список возникают лишнии символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, пути

Есть список `filebrowse` в нём содержится значение `C:\Windows\TEMP\test\test.txt` Почему при использовании функции добавления к другому списку

```
paths = patcher.append(filebrowse)
```

Добавляются лишний `\` `C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\test\\test.txt`
Как это исправить или избежать этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это символы экранирования. С обратного слэша начинаются различного рода спецсимволы, например `\t` -- это символ табуляции. В вашем случае с этими символами ничего не нужно делать, иначе путь перестанет быть корректным.

Answer (score 4):

`\` – это [символ экранирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), он экранирует символ после него. Чтобы `\` читался как обычный слэш, добавляется ещё один символ экранирования. Такой путь также будет нормально воспринят.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

qq = "C:\\scripts\\concurrent_test.py"
ww = "C:\\\\\\\\scripts\\\\\\\\concurrent_test.py"
tt = r"C:\scripts\concurrent_test.py"
print qq, ww, tt
print map(os.path.exists, (qq, ww, tt))
# C:\scripts\concurrent_test.py C:\\\\scripts\\\\concurrent_test.py C:\scripts\concurrent_test.py
# [True, True, True]
```